# I can not get this loop to stop

Tags: vb.net

I made this loop for one of my classes but for some reason the loop doesn't stop. 
Here is the code I have

```
    Dim strScore As String
    Dim intNumTests As Integer 'counter
    Dim sngSumTests As Single 'accumulator
    Dim sngAverage As Single

    strScore = InputBox("Enter the score. Click cancel when finished.", "Score Entry")

    Do While strScore <> " "
        intNumTests = intNumTests + 1     ' update Counter
        sngSumTests = sngSumTests + Val(strScore)
        strScore = InputBox("Enter the score. Click cancel when finished.", "Score Entry")
    Loop
```

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a language. As an IDE, it doesn't have loops. Please [edit] the tags to specify the actual language you're using for your code (so that it's useful to future readers, and so that it gets the attention of people watching that tag). Also, you might try using the debugger to help figure out what is causing the problem. Set a breakpoint on the first line of your code and step through it once or twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the loop to stop you must type in the InputBox a space, not the actual word `space` but press the spacebar once.

Instead of

```
Do While strScore <> " "
```

What you really wanted is

```
Do While strScore <> "" AndAlso strScore <> " "
```

or

```
Do While strScore.Length <> 0 AndAlso strScore <> " "
```

Now the `Cancel` button will work properly, and it will keep going if you don't type anything and press `OK` button.

If you press the `OK` button in InputBox and the input is empty it will return `" "` (space).
If you press the `Cancel` button in InputBox it will return `""` (empty string)

Edit:
Turns out pressing `OK` with a empty InputBox in the .NET Framework 4 also returns (empty string) so it's impossible? to detect the `Cancel` button.

Comment: where do i add the space to?